# Django - Not posting form with crispy form and datatables

Tags: python, django

I'm having trouble posting from a crispy form to my database. Below is from my views.py. Any help would be awesome!

```
class CustomerView(XEditableDatatableView):
        template_name = "customers.html"
        model = Customer
        #datatable
        datatable_options = {
            'columns': [
                        ("Title", 'Title'),
                        ("Name", 'PoC', helpers.make_xeditable),
                        ("Email", 'PoCEmail', helpers.make_xeditable),
                        ("Location", 'Location', helpers.make_xeditable),
                        ("Date Added", 'DateAdded', helpers.make_xeditable),
                        ],
            'hidden_columns': ['ID'],
                            }

    #crispy form
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CustomerView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        customer_form = CustomersForm()
        context['customer_form'] = customer_form
        return context

    #posting form
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.request.method == 'POST':
            customer_form = CustomersForm(self.request.POST)
            if customer_form.is_valid():
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('customerview'))
        else:
            customer_form = CustomersForm()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('customerview'))
```

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: What does "I'm having troube" mean? Compiler errors? Runtime error messages? What does not work like you expect?

Comment: Have you simply forgot to `customer_form.save()` after `is_valid()` by any chance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`form.is_valid()` only validate the form - then you have to use your validated data somehow. If `CustomerForm` is a `ModelForm`, you just have to call the `.save()` method:

```
        if customer_form.is_valid():
            customer_form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('customerview'))
```